# Extra blank page at the end of the report JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I've an extra white blank page at the end of the PDF, i've read other topics but the solutions didn't work for me. Does it come from the code (see below) or I've to change things in the properties? I can join the PDF if you need to.

Here is my JXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="annoncePDF" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="6fa761b0-29ca-4e21-bff3-85bd1fcb6425">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="imgPath" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[imgPath]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="localization" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[localization]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="img1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[img1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="img2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[img2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="img3" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[img3]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="img4" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[img4]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="agencyLogo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[agencyLogo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="bidType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[bidType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="realtyType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[realtyType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="realtyCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[realtyCategory]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="contactPhone" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[contactPhone]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="monthlycharges" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[monthlycharges]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="842" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="842" uuid="96dba386-3a03-44cb-84a8-34d76c4be108"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imgPath}+"/annoncePDF/template.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="138" width="595" height="257" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b39d04cd-1bfb-4211-96b7-e6123ff0679c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Left" onErrorType="Blank">
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="257" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4e070521-7016-40bd-95ea-57a8d4146c71">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{img1} != null? $F{img1}:$F{agencyLogo}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="396" y="407" width="177" height="132" uuid="44246b8b-246b-4752-8e5a-11b6c277506b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="177" height="132" uuid="8a5eb8b7-d0dc-4c87-a1ec-664eeab9d2bc">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{img4} != null? $F{img4}:$F{agencyLogo}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="209" y="407" width="177" height="132" uuid="b4536946-0dfb-4a02-a7c0-09b3f478d1f4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" onErrorType="Blank">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="177" height="132" uuid="021c1644-08c7-4b57-8abc-732a7da7a9e2">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{img3} == null?$F{agencyLogo}:$F{img3}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="22" y="407" width="177" height="132" uuid="45f9926e-65b2-4dad-a064-ce3c47156c3d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="177" height="132" uuid="b3efbb40-47e9-437f-8451-f062d7c8ddd5">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{img2} != null? $F{img2}:$F{agencyLogo}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="36" y="5" width="220" height="131" uuid="452b32ba-ca1b-4eb6-8522-93dd7282f5b2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
                    <reportElement x="17" y="0" width="150" height="131" uuid="c2241dfb-418d-4f0f-b3df-992cbab841e7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{agencyLogo}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="" x="270" y="30" width="290" height="34" forecolor="#474747" uuid="1fdc3005-be65-4654-9d21-c77757d2152e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" rotation="None" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="32" isBold="false" isItalic="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{bidType}.equals(null)?" ": $F{bidType}.toUpperCase())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="" x="232" y="64" width="328" height="30" forecolor="#303030" uuid="e49ee12b-de88-488b-b8c5-8cfb16711c3c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="32" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{realtyCategory}.equals(null)?" ": $F{realtyCategory}.toUpperCase())+" "+
($F{realtyType}.equals(null)?" ": $F{realtyType}.toUpperCase())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="" x="232" y="102" width="328" height="29" forecolor="#303030" uuid="7f9a97b2-6f5e-417a-883e-79ae479cdeac"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{localization}.equals(null)?"":$F{localization}.toUpperCase())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="260" y="558" width="300" height="160" forecolor="#424242" uuid="4a3c8f67-272b-4e71-b92d-62d2bbec64ee"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Lato Light" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="30" y="555" width="202" height="85" forecolor="#1F1F1F" uuid="1eb1157b-465d-4aec-9e58-86dc466d5426">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="23" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{realtyCategory}.equals(null)?" ": $F{realtyCategory}.toUpperCase())+" "+
($F{realtyType}.equals(null)?" ": $F{realtyType}.toUpperCase())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="30" y="637" width="202" height="73" forecolor="#1F1F1F" uuid="be6f9a34-e913-4688-b18b-d2acbdc8aaba"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="15" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{localization}.equals(null)?" ": $F{localization}.toUpperCase())+" "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="36" y="744" width="300" height="40" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="bac07815-d9bf-4635-b7ee-aec8ddfad740"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="29" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Prix : "+$F{price}+".CFP "+($F{monthlycharges}.equals("")?"": "+ "+$F{monthlycharges}+"CFP " +" de charges mensuelles")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="215" y="745" width="354" height="34" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="bf153f40-3d6a-474e-ae02-d562e6d43844"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Lato" size="21" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="0" rightIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Contact "+$F{contactPhone}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can't understand why there is a blank page at the end. I've checked the size of my images and none of them are bigger than the page itself.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !

It was not from the JXML file but in the properties of the JXML. I had to click on

> Ignore pagination

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I put All list component in frame 
this fixed my problem.